# Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl() always return last result I select

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to play the mp3 files which are stored on Firebase storage by getting downloadUrl.
I use two spinners to decide the music types and music name which matches the folder name and file name on storage.

But after the first time choosing, the Uri I get is Null.
When I choose the second one the Uri I get is the first one I just choose.
I choose the third one, I get the second one and so on.

Here is the code I get the Url.

```
private void prepareMusic() {
    btnPlay.setText(getString(R.string.btnplay));
    btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);

    mStorageRef.child("music/"+musicType+"/"+musicName).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            uriTest = uri.toString();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            //uriTest =" ";
        }
    });
//the toast here is the correct type and name I choose
    Toast.makeText(this,"Now musicType is: " + musicType + " musicName is:" + musicName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//the Uri here is always last one I choose and null at beginning
    Toast.makeText(this,"uri is: " + uriTest, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try{
        mper.reset();
        mper.setDataSource(uriTest);
        mper.prepareAsync();
    }catch (Exception e){
        tos.setText(getString(R.string.setTrackError) + e.toString());
        tos.show();
    }
}
```

I have searched lots of question here, but there is not a good answer to deal with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDownloadUrl()` is asynchronous and returns immediately after it's called with a Task object that represents the work in progress.  Your code will then display two toasts *before* the download url is available.

You should only be using the download URL from the moment that the success callback is invoked, so move your code in there, or call a method in there that uses the URL.

To learn more about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous, [read this blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll try to fix the problem by the reference you give.