# Not getting actual url path of uploaded image on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to access the actual URL of uploaded image on firebase, but not getting.

Look at my code below:

```
String ActualImageUrl = null;
    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
{
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
        {
            ActualImageUrl = uri.toString();
            Log.d("okok","url inside: "+ActualImageUrl);
        }
    });
Log.d("okok","url ouside: "+ActualImageUrl);
```

okok: url inside: ACTUAL URL HERE
okok: url outside: null

Comment: Your `url` will always `null` outside the callback since the `onSuccess()` method has an asynchronous behavior. So please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Comment: @AlexMamo Please don't mark questions as a duplicate of a question that is about a different product. While the link may be useful, it can't be a duplicate.

Comment: @Jatinder: as Alex commented, the `onSuccess` is called *after* your `Log.d("okok","url ouside: "+ActualImageUrl);` has run, so it logs the `ActualImageUrl` before `onSuccess` has updated it. Any code that needs the download URL needs to be inside `onSuccess` or be called from there. For an example see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127996/getdownloadurl-isnt-inputting-the-link-i-need/53128190#53128190, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802185, and probably a few more from this list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D%5Bandroid%5D+download+URL+asynchronous

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Copy that, thanks puf.

Answer (score 1):

From [Firebase Official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) use this code to get download url

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
@Override
public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        throw task.getException();
    }

    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
    return ref.getDownloadUrl();
}
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
    } else {
        // Handle failures
        // ...
    }
}
});
```

Comment: there is no uploadTask.continueWithTask() method

Comment: I done it. What I did is:                                                  
    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
{
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
        { //  create a user object by passing name as well as URL of the image
            User u = new User(userName, uri.toString());
        }
    }); // finally I can get the name as well as URL from that object anywhere